# Why do Outbound URL Rewrite rules require an XmlSerializers.dll

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, xmlserializer, sgen

I'm trying to enable OutboundRules in the rewrite section of a web.config to convert all .html extensions to extensionless.

However, when I add any rule (it doesn't matter what it contains), I receive a 500 error stating that .XmlSerializers.dll cannot be found (note that it's the data project that is erroring, not the web project).  As soon as I remove the outboundRules section, the site starts working again.

```
HTTP Error 500.52 - URL Rewrite Module Error.

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly '<data project>.XmlSerializers' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. File name: '<data project>.XmlSerializers' 
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) 
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.LoadWithPartialNameInternal(AssemblyName an, Evidence securityEvidence, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) 
WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

I've tried actually generating the XmlSerializer locally using sgen, and it fails with the following error:

```
 Error: Cannot deserialize type 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataTypeAttribute' because it contains property 'DataType' which has no public setter.
```

So my assumption is that OutboundRules always requires the XmlSerializer, however, it's always generated on the fly.  In this situation it fails silently to generate on-the-fly, and therefore we get that error.

So, first how can make the Serializer work? and second, why is it required?